# Throwing custom exception inside try, while throwing same custom exception in catch

Tags: java

Is this acceptable or considered bad practice?

```
public void method() {
    try {
       throw new MyException("Error occurred");
    } catch(Exception e) {
       throw new MyException("Something went wrong");
    }
}
```

I am throwing my custom exception but catching generic exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific code snippet is bad practice. The *general principle* can be acceptable, but there's a nicer style way to do it.

Let's take it step by step

### The snippet is silly

Here you will actually catch the very exception you throw and then just throw a new one. In other words, `"Error occurred"` **cannot possibly** be the message of the MyEx that this method throws, and the stack trace will be pointing at the second `throw new` line. The first `throw new` line is pretty much just a really weird, unreadable way to say 'go to catch block and ignore this exception'.

We can trivially fix this:

```
try {
  throw new MyException("msg1");
} catch (MyException e) {
  throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new MyException("msg2", e);
}
```

### error 1: Failure to preserve causal chain

When throwing an exception due to *another* exception, you should add the original exception to the causal chain. The original exception (the one that caused your catch block to trigger) presumably  contains important information. See the above snippet, where you pass along the caught exception as second argument. Yes, you will have to update your own exception, you can just:

```
class MyEx extends Exception {
  public MyEx(String msg) {
    super(msg);
  }

  public MyEx(String msg, Throwable cause) {
    super(msg, cause);
  }
}
```

If you are working with a code base that simply doesn't have this and you cannot change it, you can call `.initCause()` which is designed *solely* to be used in cases where you are working with legacy code that you cannot change.

### error 2: The message is silly

This may simply have been code written for the question and not your real code, but exception type names need to be about what the problem is, and the message needs to contain that information that is useful **on top of** the type. Don't repeat things. For example, this is the perfect exception behaviour:

```
// Some hypothetical file system driver
if (!someFileSystemCheckForFileExistence(filePathToLookfor)) {
  throw new NoSuchFileException(filePathToLookFor);
```

Note that:

- The exception's type name itself accurately describes the issue, namely: A file was requested that does not exist.
- The message solely adds pertinent information and doesn't repeat itself. It's just the file name.

Examples of bad takes:

- `throw new RuntimeException("Something went wrong");`

Neither the message nor the type is useful here. Very bad.

- `throw new RuntimeException("File not found");`

The type isn't useful so it's hard to programatically react to this (if ever you are disassembling the message with `substring` or regexes, you know you messed this up). Also, the message could be more useful by indicating *which* file wasn't found.

- `throw new NoSuchFileException("Not found: " + filePath);`

Decent but could be better - `Not found:`  is superfluous; the exception type already covers the idea that something wasn't found, there's no need for the message to *also* say it.

- `throw new NoSuchFileException("Error: " + filePath + "!");`

Do not end exception messages in punctuation, *especially* exclamation mark. Yes, yes, it's an error, errors bad. We already know this, it's annoying for everybody (readers and those writing the code that throws them) to add an exclamation mark. It's an exception that made it to human eyeballs. Involved parties understand this is a bad thing, there is no need for hysterics with the exclamation marks.

### error 3: Catching generic exception

catching `Throwable`, `Exception`, or `RuntimeException` *can be* fine, but you need to know what you are doing. It's fine *only* in cases where you are a 'launch point runner'.

Launch Points are places where code more or less starts. You're surely already familiar with one various obvious LP, which is `public static void main(String[] args) {}`. That method is a launch point. But it's not the only one - if you're writing code in a web framework, you tend not to write your own main. Even if you do, what you really write is a collection of tiny little apps - one app per URL to be handled. Each 'URL handler' is itself a launch point.

Launch Points should usually be declared to `throws Exception` (that's what your `main` should look like!), and, whether it does or not, the code that *calls* a launch point, should catch *ALL* exceptions. Often you do not, yourself, write such code: The OpenJDK team wrote the code that calls `main`, you don't. Generally you have some web framework like dropwizard or spring you're using, and the authors of that framework wrote the code that calls your URL endpoint handlers. But *that* code either uses `catch (Exception e)` (and that would be correct), or they don't and their framework is kinda crappy as a result.

The reason you want that is that any exception anywhere generally means execution should bubble up and abort every method call in the chain until we get to the launch point runner itself, and it generally can add a ton of information. Imagine a URL endpoint: If an error happens that you cannot recover from (say, the DB is down and someone tries to log in. The user account info is in the db we cannot get to, so what possible point is there to continuing? The one and only option left to us, is to tell the user some error occurred, to log the issue, and to trigger any 'call the sysops team for help' routines that are available if required (i.e. if they don't trigger off of watchdogs or log messages).

**all** of that is generic, in the sense that you have boatloads of endpoints that are all in the same boat: if DB down, there's nothing left to do except those 3 things.

You really, *really* do not want to repeat those 3 complex steps in all 384 URL endpoint handlers your webapp has. The best strategy by far is to ensure your endpoint handlers can easily trigger this 'okay, show error to user, log it properly, trigger sysop calls if needed' code and to never be enticed into writing simpler, worse handling code.

The best way? Simply. Leave. Exceptions. Be. Let them bubble up to the place that knows how to handle them generically. For example, a URL launch point runner will catch all exceptions, and log them *with* pertinent info from the request, such as headers or the IP (which will help if the exception is caused by some malicious actor probing for weaknesses in your site!). The standard exception handler doesn't know how to add IP info, so if you ever write, anywhere:

```
try {
  stuff();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

stop what you are doing - that's always bad code. That code will fail to trigger the baked in Launch Point Runner mechanism, and will in fact continue which will likely result in more exceptions. Assuming all exception handling is written as above, then 1 error causes 50 stack traces, most of which are completely useless, and none of the failsafes are triggered. Horrible.

Solution: The 'fire and forget' catch block is best written as:

```
try {
  code();
} catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("unhandled", e);
}
```

Which will ensure the exception can bubble up, aborts code execution, ensures the LPR can deal with it and add what it needs to add, is easy to write. Yes, open your editor, update its templates.

**other** than "I am writing a Launch Point Runner" it is unlikely that `catch (Exception e)` is proper code style. Wrapping exceptions often is correct, but catch the specific issues, not 'all exceptions'.

Comment: Question on your first answer. You have two catch blocks where the first catch block is just catching MyException and then throwing it again. Why is that good practice? Since my original answer will have both MyException and Exception thrown so there is no loss of information.

Comment: Because it ensure the _second_ catch block will not catch `MyException`. Yo uwant `MyException` to fall through, and anything else to be wrapped. _if_ you dealt with all other points.